# How to programatically compare an entire row in R?

Tags: r, select, dataframe

I have the following dataframe in R:
`data=
Time X1 X2 X3
   1  1  0  0
   2  1  1  1
   3  0  0  1
   4  1  1  1
   5  0  0  0
   6  0  1  1
   7  1  1  1
   8  0  0  0
   9  1  1  1
  10  0  0  0`

Is there a way to programatically select those rows that are equal to (0,1,1)? I know it can be done by doing `data[data$X1 == 0 & data$X2 == 1 & data$X3 == 1,]` but, in my scenario, (0,1,1) is a list in a variable. My ultimate goal here is to determine the number of rows that are equal to (0,1,1), or any other combination that list variable can hold.

Thanks!

Mariano.

Comment: Are you sure you really need a dataframe and not a matrix?

Comment: Thanks @user31264! I'm importing that data from a file and I'm getting a dataframe at this point. I'm new to R so it may be another way of doing this and get it in a different structure!

Comment: If you need a matrix, you can perform `as.matrix`  after you read it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here's a couple of options using a `merge`:

```
merge(list(X1=0,X2=1,X3=1), dat)
#or
merge(setNames(list(0,1,1),c("X1","X2","X3")), dat)
```

Or even using positional indexes based on what columns you want matched up:

```
L <- list(0,1,1)
merge(L, dat, by.x=seq_along(L), by.y=2:4)
```

All of which return:

```
#  X1 X2 X3 Time
#1  0  1  1    6
```

If your matching variables are all of the same type, you could also safely do it via matrix comparison like:

```
dat[colSums(t(dat[c("X1","X2","X3")]) == c(0,1,1)) == 3,]
```

Comment: Thank you @thelatemail! This would definitely do it, I tried different things and I think I was missing the transpose operation. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

`apply(data, 1, function(x) all(x==c(0,1,1)))`

This will go down each row of the frame and return `TRUE` for each row where the row is equal to `c(0,1,1)`.

Answer (score 0):

this is your data

```
mydf <- structure(list(Time = 1:10, X1 = c(1L, 1L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 
0L, 1L, 0L), X2 = c(0L, 1L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 1L, 1L, 0L, 1L, 0L), 
    X3 = c(0L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 0L, 1L, 1L, 0L, 1L, 0L)), .Names = c("Time", 
"X1", "X2", "X3"), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -10L
))
```

Using subset

```
subset(mydf, X1 == 0 & X2==1 & X3==1)
#  Time X1 X2 X3
#6    6  0  1  1
```

another way

```
mydf[mydf$X1 ==0 & mydf$X2 ==1 & mydf$X3 ==1, ] 
#   Time X1 X2 X3
#6    6  0  1  1
```

or like this

```
mydf[mydf$X1 ==0 & mydf$X2 & mydf$X3 %in% c(1,1), ]
#  Time X1 X2 X3
#6    6  0  1  1
```

you can also do that by

```
library(dplyr)
filter(mydf, X1==0 & X2==1 & X3==1)
#   Time X1 X2 X3
#1    6  0  1  1
```